# Spring Error- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, spring

I am getting the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, when running as Java application

This is for Spring where I had created a SpringConfig.xml file calling it from TestSpringProject class using ApplicationContext interface. I had not used and dependency tool..just imported the required jars of spring

TestSpringProject.java:

```java
public class TestSpringProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml");

        Restaurant res = (Restaurant) context.getBean("restaurantBean");
        res.greetCustomer();

    }

}
```

SpringConfig.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="restaurantBean" class="com.packages.Restaurant.java">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Restaurant.java:

```java
public class Restaurant {

    public void greetCustomer() {
        System.out.println("Welcome Customer");
    }
}
```

Expected result: Welcome Customer

Actual result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:160)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:230)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:62)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.packages.TestSpringProject.main(TestSpringProject.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:71)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of the issue is in the sentence that you've stated by yourself:

> > I had not used and dependency tool..just imported the required jars of spring

Spring by itself depends on thirdparty libraries, for example commons-logging.
Usually dependency management tools (like maven from this standpoint) have a concept of transitive dependency, meaning that if your project depends on spring and spring depends on commons logging, then you actually depend on common logging in a sense that you won't be able to run the project even if your code doesn't depend on commons-logging by itself.

So you should at minimum import this commons logging jar, however I really recommend you managing the project in some build tool that can resolve these transitive dependencies, because even if you'll resolve this issue, there will be other issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is Working Fine, There might be some issues with Dependency (jars). You may try downloading the latest version from here - https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/